# How is formula specified in R's lm function

Tags: r

I have a function in R, lets say

```
myfunction <- function(formula,data)
```

Among other things, the function contains a call to lm(). Formula should include the covariates, and should be specified as

formula = x1 + x2 + ... + x_n

Data contains columns Z and W, where the response

```
y=data$Z/data$W
```

I only want to have formula including the covariates, since the function modifies the response variable for each iteration.

The call for lm() should then work with

```
lm(y~formula,data=data)
```

Comment: This is an incomplete example: for one thing, where does your `y` come from? (One would hope there's a `data$y` but you haven't specified). What is "xblock" ?

Comment: Paste together the formula (using `paste` or `paste0` as @RockScience demostrated) and pass that formula object to your `lm` call.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have edited the question, for more clarification

Answer (score 1):

why would you do that? It is cleaner to pass the whole formula in `myfunction`, for instance:

```
myfunction <- function(formula,data) {
   data = data*2   # this is an example of data manipulation
   lm(formula=formula, data=data)
}
```

then use `myfunction` as you would use `lm`

If you REALLY want to create complexity (for nothing?), you can also use the fact that `lm` will coerce whatever `string` you pass as an argument into a proper `formula` object

```
myfunction2 <- function(formula2,data) {
   data = data*2   # this is an example of data manipulation
   lm(formula=paste0("y~",formula2), data=data)
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, why this data=data*2 ?

Comment: @Acarbalacar he's just giving an example of how you might manipulate your input dataframe `data` into the actual formula you wish to perform a fit to .

Comment: the reason behind it, is that the response variable gets modified in the function, so I cannot specify that in the function arguments